# Date expression in SSRS Report builder for Oracle dataset

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report in SSRS Report builder where the Date_from parameter from the MS SQL dataset takes the following expression that returns the previous day if the Schedule (another parameter) value is 0, and the first day of the previous month if the Schedule is 1

```
=FormatDateTime(IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!Date_from.Value),
Switch( Parameters!Schedule.Value = 0,DateAdd("d",-1,Today()),
        Parameters!Schedule.Value = 1,DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), "1").AddMonths(-1)) 
,Parameters!Date_from.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

I need to rewrite it to add to the dataset from Oracle.

I've tried with sysdate, and with case but it keeps saying they are not declared:

The Value expression for the query parameter ':Date_from' contains an error: [BC30451] 'SYSDATE' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

For example this is the dataset (simplified version)

```
select valuedate,refnum
from table d
where and d.valuedate >= :Date_from
and d.valuedate < :Date_to
```

Comment: That's an SSRS expression, it has no direct relationship to the database. I guess the issue is in the dataset query itself.

Comment: I have 2 datasets in the same report in SSRS, one from MS and the other from Oracle. They both need to have the same expression for date_from and date_to parameters. The MS expression is described in the question, I just need to adjust it to work for the Oracle dataset as well so they both return the same date. Hope this helps))

Comment: I understand but the error is actually occurring in the Oracle dataset query. I can't help with that but I suggest you post the dataset query or a simplified version of it that reproduces the error. Then I'm sure you'll get some answers.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Added the query sample

Comment: I have no Oracle experience, but take a look at this, it might help. I suspect the date format you are passing is incorrect so it may need to be parsed in your query . 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229575/passing-date-parameters-to-oracle-query-in-ssrs

Comment: Try to pass the parameter as a string and wrap it in to_date to perform an explicit conversion in Oracle SQL. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm

Comment: Yea that did the trick, I wraped it in to_date, and replaced today() with now() in parameter expression. Thank you))